# Как добавить свой класс к ссылкам в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как можно задать класс ссылкам в своем меню? Через админку классы задаются li в котором лежит ссылка, при использовании

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){

        $classes[] = "my_test_class";
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Ничего не происходит. Есть еще какие-то варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде опечатка:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
function special_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
    $classes[] = "my_test_class";

    return $classes;
}
```

Если этот код не работает, то скорее всего меню у вас выведено какими-то плагинами или костылями